# Is there a Nginx configuration to block IE10 DNT?

Tags: nginx, configuration

Apache has a patch to block the Do Not Track header for Internet Explorer 10.  What Nginx configuration change can I use to do the same?

Comment: Thinking a combination of more_set_input_headers (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule#more_set_input_headers) and something with the IE user agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When nginx is a reverse proxy to upstream backend servers, use [`proxy_set_header`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_set_header), something like this:

```
proxy_set_header DNT ""
```

When sending to FastCGI/FPM, such as in the case of PHP, use [`fastcgi_hide_header`](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_hide_header), for example:

```
fastcgi_hide_header DNT
```

Keep in mind you'll have to wrap this in an `if` to test for IE 10, and [If is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil), so this configuration will probably come back to bite you. If you only have one `if` in the `location` block, you'll probably be OK...

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ Trident/6.0) {
    proxy_set_header DNT ""
}
```

Comment: Wanted to avoid "if", but this might be the only way do this